# Regarding iphone distribution private key issue

Tags: ios, app-store, distribution, private-key

I want to upload my app to app store. My client has given his own apple id for uploading for his account. I tried to install the distribution certificate of my client's account on my Mac but it is not working for me. The private key is missing in that certificate.

What do I have to do for this to work?

Comment: from ITC, your client should be able to generate a valid certificate for you once you've been added to his team, and then you could use it. I think that's the way I did it.

Answer (score 5):

He will have the the key stored in the **Keychain Access** application in his mac..

Tell him to export the key **.p12** format and send you..If you import that key and the certificate .. you will be able to upload the app

the Key Name will be the same as done in when you request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority..The name you entered there for the certificate is the key to be extracted.

Comment: thanks shubbank i ask my client regarding this and get back to you.

Comment: Correct, there's some issues regarding exporting keys as .p12, so you might need to have him export the public/private pair as a .keychain. This can be done by creating a separate keychain and moving the keys here. Have the customer zip this "directory" and send it to you.